# SQL Server TEMP_DB initialization task is deadlocked

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012. This process on tempdb is going on which blocking my application to use database and I am getting

> deadlocked on lock | generic waitable object resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

The pid in this error is of temp_db operation which is executing below thing

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @previous_collection_time datetime;
DECLARE @previous_request_count bigint;
DECLARE @current_collection_time datetime;
DECLARE @current_request_count bigint;
DECLARE @batch_requests_per_sec bigint;
DECLARE @interval_sec bigint;

-- Get the previous snapshot's time and batch request count
SELECT TOP 1 @previous_collection_time = collection_time, @previous_request_count = request_count 
FROM #am_request_count
ORDER BY collection_time DESC;

-- Get the current total time and batch request count
SET @current_collection_time = GETDATE();
SELECT @current_request_count = cntr_value 
FROM sys.sysperfinfo
WHERE counter_name = 'Batch Requests/sec' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;

SET @interval_sec = 
    -- Avoid divide-by-zero
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF (second, @previous_collection_time, @current_collection_time) = 0 THEN 1
        ELSE DATEDIFF (second, @previous_collection_time, @current_collection_time)
    END;

-- Calc the Batch Requests/sec rate for the just-completed time interval. 
SET @batch_requests_per_sec = (@current_request_count - @previous_request_count) / @interval_sec;

-- Save off current batch count
INSERT INTO #am_request_count (collection_time, request_count) 
VALUES (@current_collection_time, @current_request_count);

-- Return the batch requests/sec rate for the just-completed time interval. 
SELECT ISNULL (@batch_requests_per_sec, 0) AS batch_requests_per_sec;

-- Get rid of all but the most recent snapshot's data
DELETE FROM #am_request_count WHERE collection_time < @current_collection_time;
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: To resolve a deadlock, you need to find the killer and the victim. A deadlock occurs because neither can finish while they both are executing.

Comment: Victim is the tempdb operation its always keep runinng

Comment: I believe that query is executed by the SSMS Activity Monitor. So go find out who has opened that SSMS window and close it.

Comment: Any other idea , its not working